# Como extrair dados do Facebook com Pyhon?

Tags: python, api, facebook

Estou querendo entender melhor o comportamento das pessoas que curtiram a minha página; quem são e o que curtem. 
É possível eu obter esses dados pessoais de usuários (nome, cidade, idade, curtidas) com o python no facebook? Ou o Facebook me nega o acesso a isso?

Comment: Votei para fechar a pergunta como insuficientemente clara por não apresentar informações necessárias para possibilitar uma resposta concisa. Entretanto, recomento que você leia sobre a SDK do Facebook para Python (ou a própria API) para se informar melhor se é ou não possível fazer o que deseja.

Comment: Não acho que seja necessário fechar a pergunta, mas orientar uma edição.

Comment: Possível é, mas a pergunta está um bocado vaga. Seria bom dizer o que tentou, que informações levaram à questão de "negar o acesso", qual a dificuldade real encontrada, etc. Fica a sugestão de leitura em [Ask] e [Help] para se situar melhor com o formato do site. Lembrando que sempre pode [Edit] a pergunta, mesmo depois de fechada.

Comment: A pergunta pode ter uma resposta objetiva sim, e que se for bem feita pode dar o caminho das pedras para muita gente. Entendo que não há uma tentativa do OP colocada na pergunta, mas são "que passos seguir até chegar lá". Fuidar uma olhada,e a documentação na internet é esparça. Eu mesmo tropecei num ponto, e não consegui desenvolver um roteiro completo - será um grande ganho ter uma boa resposta pra essa pergunta.